# Insert contacts Last Name using Intent android

Tags: android, insert, contacts, contactscontract

Google should really document their contacts API, its really irritating to find out how to insert specific details.

Anyways,

I want to send following contact details to `Contact` native application of android:

1. Name
2. Last Name [Family Name]
3. Street Address
4. City
5. State
6. Zip Code
7. Contact Phone no.

I have figured out that Family name is stored in `ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.FAMILY_NAME`

Anyhelp will really be appreciated. And if you know any other columns insertion beyond these mentioned. I am ready to buy it. Only condition is it should use ContactsContract i.e. above android 2.1 API Level 5

Thankx :)

Comment: Hello, I also working for the same..did you anyhow managed to pass Family name? please if you have found the way..tell me..thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

To set the name, your code would be like :

```
ConactsIntent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.NAME, firstName);
```

Try Adding a space in between first name and the last name.

```
ConactsIntent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.NAME, firstName+" "+lastName);
```

Comment: And what happens with compound nouns?

Answer (score 0):

```
ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.STREET
ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.CITY
ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.REGION
ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.POSTCODE
ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER
```

You'll find all of them [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.html).